# mopub for private ads publishing

Tags: android, mopub

I have an android app and i would like to put some native ads and in-app ads in them. I took a look at multiple providers such as TapJoy / adMob / Flurry etc. They all aggregate publishers and allow devs to show the ads and make money.

BUT, my requirement is different, i want to publish ONLY MY ADS and not from other publishers. In other words, i want the simple SDK integration that moPub does but do not want other publishers to push ads.

I saw that in moPub, if i dont subscribed to marketplace, i kinda achieve what i want as my ads just show up my "creatives" or "ads"

What is the catch? Can i continue using mopub for private publishing?

Sorry, if the question is too elementary, i am new to this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Experts, has it not got anybody's attention? Some points please?